# How to remove some type checks from a function parameter in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following type:

```js
type test = {
   test1: number
   test2: number
   test3: number
}
```

and the function

```js
function bla(data: test) {}
```

Now, the idea is that wherever I call `bla` from, I can't pass the data which will have `test1, test2, test3`, but only `test2, test3`. Typescript will complain that I don't pass the data which has all the `test1, test2, test3`.

How would you solve such problem?

Comment: Are you wanting optional types?

Comment: But what is the problem? That TS does not allow you to pass an invalid value for that type? Or that you don't know how to make the type valid for your data?

Comment: Would [Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) help here?

Comment: How about `Omit<test, "test1">`?

Comment: I would improve title and question too, I would not use words like scream, but explain exactly the issue / scenario

Comment: Based on the comments on the existing answers it seems like they've uncovered what you're after (modifying a library-defined type) so please update the question appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

You can `Omit` properties from an object type:

```
type OmitTest = Omit<test, "test1">;
```

Which is the same as:

```
type OmitTest = {
  test2: number;
  test3: number;
}
```

Or create a `Partial` to make all properties optional:

```
type PartialTest = Partial<test>;
```

Which is the same as:

```
type PartialTest = {
  test1?: number;
  test2?: number;
  test3?: number;
}
```

**Edit**:

You could create a mapped, intersected type using `Omit` which allows you to pick certain properties from the original object as optional:

```
type PickPartial<
  T extends {[key: string]: any}, 
  Keys extends keyof T
> = Omit<T, Keys> & {[K in Keys]?: T[K]};

type PickPartialTest = PickPartial<test, "test1">;
```

Which comes out as:

```
type PickPartialTest = {
  test1?: number;
  test2: number;
  test3: number;
}
```

This will work with a union of any keys from the object `T`.

Comment: Thanks a lot... Makes sense. Though, is there any way I can decide which one to be required and which one optional ?

Comment: See the edit. I think that's what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the `test1` property optional like this:

```
type test =  {
   test1?: number
   test2: number
   test3: number
}
```

As I understand your question you need to override types from an external library.

Then create a `custom-typings.d.ts` file in your `src` folder and fill it like this:

```
type test =  {
    test1?: number
    test2: number
    test3: number
 }

// let's say you use import { bla } from 'your-exact-library-name';
declare module 'your-exact-library-name' {
    declare function bla(data: test): any;
}
```

After that you'll be able to call the function with your own type.

Comment: thanks for the follow up. The problem is that the `type test` is coming from 3rd party. and I can't touch it. but I still want to be using it, since I pass the data to my functiion which has almost 90% of the variables from `test`.